# batch command file windows

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, command

if there is any way to run notepad if something was copied and make it checking every 5 minutes?

```
for %%F in (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) do (
    xcopy /e e:\%%F  f:\
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to complete the first part of your question but to time out for 5 mins you could use a code similar to this: 
`echo CODE`
`echo Sleep 5 mins` 
`TIMEOUT /T 300 /NOBREAKS`
`echo MORE CODE`
 Obviously change 300 to the number of seconds you desire if 5 mins is too short/long!
 I would also suggest not using a batch file for this if you can!

Comment: Then try `ping -n 300 127.0.0.1 > nul`
(Also I apologize I didn't know `timeout` was not available before Vista)

Comment: The switch to `timeout` is also called `/nobreak` as the documentation reveals.